# php message Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Tags: javascript, php

This is my javascript

```
function ajax_post(){
            // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
            var url = "LiveUpdate.php";
            var sb = document.getElementById("LiveUpdate").value;
            var FirstName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
            var images = document.getElementById("images").value;

            var vars = "update="+sb+"&FirstName="+FirstName+"&images="+images;
            hr.open("POST", url, true);
            // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
            }
            // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
            var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
            hr.send(formData); // Actually execute the request // Actually execute the request
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "processing...";
        }
            //show image before uploading
                var loadFile = function(event) {
                var output = document.getElementById('output');
                output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                };//end image
```

and this is the form. javascript and the form is in the same file. the file name is sample.php

```
<form action="popup.php" method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <img src="" id="output" />
    <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonBefore="true" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onchange="loadFile(event)" name="images" id="images">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button" name="update" id="LiveUpdate"  onclick="javascript:ajax_post();">Update</a>
</form>
```

the idea in this code is. i want to insert the basic information like FirstName and Image into the database live without refreshing the page. the reason why i choose  tag to submit the ajax. so the page url Account.php?Edit=1 will not change to Account.php because if it change to account.php the popup editing mode will be close. the problem in this code is. i don't know how to fix the error `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0` can anyone help me how to fix this. thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635738/warning-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post-data-in-unknown-on-line-0)

Answer (score 48):

The browser sets the correct headers (including the correct multipart boundary indication in the Content-type) if you haven't manually specified anything.

So all you need to do is remove the following line:

```
 hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Otherwise you will need to set the boundary yourself as it is suggested by Ellias Van Ootegem in  [Uploading a file with XMLHttprequest - Missing boundary in multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348216/uploading-a-file-with-xmlhttprequest-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data):

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
```

Comment: As per comment here by  Elias Van Ootegem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348216/uploading-a-file-with-xmlhttprequest-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: Man I have spent a whole day trying to send form data. That did the trick. Thanks so much !

Comment: Adding the `boundary` to the `Content-Type` header fixed my problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the setRequestHeader()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works as well. Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
        "Content-Type":
          "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575"
      }
    };