# Angular 5 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' gets reset to 'application/json'

Tags: angular, express, angular5, multer, angular-httpclient

Hi I am having trouble trying to get my httpClient patch request to send FormData with content type 'multipart/form-data'.

I have specified the headers as shown:

```js
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache'
    })
  };
```

And I do the following to save to the nodejs server:

```js
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('materialFile', 'something');
return this.httpClient.patch<any>(this.apiUrl  + loan.id, formData, this.httpOptions);
```

On my Nodejs/Express server I do the following:

```js
const Multer  = require('multer');

router.patch('/:id', Multer().fields([{ name: "materialFile", maxCount: 1 }]), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files['materialFile']);
});
```

When I inspect the request headers on the browser I see that the content-type is application/json.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Why are you sending form data in a PATCH request? Form data is supposed to be sent in a POST, I think angular is recognizing this and instead changes the content type on you

Comment: @Dummy I changed it to post and it still does the same thing

Comment: if you want to received the full response use observe:response, see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: Can you please show xhr request status in browser's developer tools?
(Ctrl+shift+i) -> network -> xhr
Send the request from your app and show that xhr response @ShaunChua

Comment: @Debojyoti Interceptor was the issue, thank you

Comment: did you remove the content-type when setting headers in interceptors to make multipart/form-data apply ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Angular tries to automatically set http header `content-type` according to request body, so there is absolutely no need to set it manually. If the content-type header is `application/json` in browser's devtools that means request body has been changed till angular's attempt to define the header. That change most probably happens in interceptors. So if you have an interceptor, that makes manipulation on the request, the issue is probably at that point.

Comment: You absolutely saved my life! God Bless!

Comment: I have to agree! I spent almost a week and many many many lost hours only to find out my angular app had a jwt interceptor that was forcing the header to be application/json. The silly part is i never caught it because i was still sending the headers with my posts so i didnt think i set any defaults but i sure did. This is my new favourite post!

Answer (score 2):

As Hikmat G. pointed out, the problem is most likely steming from an Http interceptor, in my case, i found out that in my Authorization interceptor that i use to inject the JWT Token was setting the content-type to `application/json` as shown below :

```
    return req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type' :  'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${ token }`,
        },
    });
```

and i did need it that way, except for a certain request where i was sending a file as part of a formdata object, where the content type had to be `multipart/form-data`, it would be automatically changed to json, so i added in a condition to avoid that problem and it seemed to be working :

```
        let json_blacklist = "/example/url";
        let reqHeaders = {
            setHeaders: {
            'Content-Type' :  'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${ token }`,
            },
        };

        if(req.url.includes(json_blacklist)) {
            delete reqHeaders.setHeaders["Content-Type"];
        }

        return req.clone(reqHeaders);
```

**Tip :** For requests where you're sending files, don't set the content-type to multipart/form-data, just remove the content type altogether and allow for the browser to set the content type by itself, this will help prevent webkit boundaries error as the browser will automatically set the boundaries, See [#40561738](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561738/php-message-warning-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post-data-in-unknow) for more details.