# How to send form data having file as input by Ajax technique using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I tried this way-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax file submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        file<input type="file" name="my_file">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn">
    </form>
<!-- SCRIPT FOR THE ABOVE FORM -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let my_form=document.getElementById("my_form");
        let my_file=my_form.elements[0];
        let submit_btn=my_form.elements[1];
        my_form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        submit_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            //let data = my_file.name+"="+my_file.value+"&&"+submit_btn.name+"="+submit_btn.value+"&&";
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "ajax_file_process.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
                console.log("upload is fired");
                console.log(e);
            })
            //xhr.send(data);
            //console.log(new FormData(my_form));
            xhr.send(new FormData(my_form));

            xhr.onload = () => {
                console.log("onload is fired");
                if (xhr.status==200){
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

//code in ajax_file_process.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit_btn"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["my_file"]["name"];
    $file_size=$_FILES["my_file"]["size"];
    $file_type=$_FILES["my_file"]["type"];
    $file_tmp_loc=$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"];

    $file=time()."_".$file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_loc, "images/".$file);
}
?>
```

The response I received is **"Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data on line0"**.

One thing that I could analyze is upload progress only work before sending xhr data i.e. when **xhr.send()** is applied after upload. Hence there is need to be done with with the uploaded data which is uploaded in many parts as seen in console.

Second way I tried is by **xhr.send(data)** and data variable is collected from form as I have mentioned this as comment in script part. But, failed to get desired result or move the file to the location where I want by php.
Since, I started programming 2 ago, and not able to find answer.
Kindly correct the issue with pure  javascript.
Your answer is always appreciable.
Thank you.

Comment: While writing descriptions I focused more to code rather than text decoration. Anyways thanks a lot for reminding my mistakes.

Comment: Still waiting for solution to the problem, anyone kindly help me to get out of this.

Comment: did you check the popular answer in a similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635738/warning-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post-data-in-unknown-on-line-0
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348216/uploading-a-file-with-xmlhttprequest-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data
and some other - try searching for your problem first

Comment: I searched too much but, not found satisfying result.

Comment: @Palo, I worked on your suggestion added few lines to script before http request as - let file = my_file.files[0];
   let formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("filer", file, true);  and made changes to send as - xhr.send(formdata); removed header,  added boundry to header as per the users comments as - xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=same-as-the-boundary-in-request-body"); and xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2)); but, not able to move the file.